# Do Museos exist in anything other than T. A. Barron's Merlin series? What originated the idea?

Tags: history-of, merlin, ta-barron

In T. A. Barron's *Merlin* series, a creature mentioned a few times by Barron is the Museo. A Museo is a creature that can produce a single note that carries the weight and meaning of an entire song. Its call is said to be the most beautiful in all the realms. However, I've never heard any mention to it in other franchises - not in *The Chronicles of Narnia*, *The Lord of the Rings*, or anything else I've read or watched. Where did this creature come from? Barron took a lot of things from ancient British and Celtic myths. In addition, is the Museo a part of any other franchise?

Comment: I have read 1000+ fantasy books, and I have never read of any creature like that, by any name. Not that this proves anything - it is very hard to prove a negative.

Comment: the problem with "museo" is that it has meant "museum" essentially since Ancient Greece and it is the Latin singular something or other. IN the book it is a blue teardrop creature with gold fleck IIRC. I *suspect* the author was thinking of a "muse" (lower case) and just added an -o suffix (muse-O, rather than mus-eo maybe?). The -o suffix was very productive for cheap product names 50s-70s (see: Wham-O)

Comment: I was going to suggest that the author was providing their own respelling of [muso](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/muso#English), but then I see they are American, not Commonwealth. Although they might well have heard the word while at Oxford.